# Saving log of each Activity in ADF pipeline to ADLS

Tags: azure, logging, azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have this ADF pipeline

[image: 1]

Ι want to save the output with Name, Type, Status, Duration (same like in pipeline debug output) for each run to Azure Data Lake Storage. The process should be automatic, don't want to use 'Export to CSV' manually since i don't know when job will run.
Is there any way i can achieve this?

I tried many logging options available but all gives details of pipeline run, not of activities within it. 'Set Variable' before and after of each activity is an option but that will complicate my flow as I have many activities within it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want logs of all activities, pipelines into a file.

You can log all the Pipeline runs,trigger runs,Activity runs segregated fashion USING **"Azure Monitor"** all at one go .No need of any extra pipeline/stored procedures/set variables .All the info will be logged in yyyy-->Mm-->dd-->hh-->mm-->ss fashion in your storage account in form of **Json format**.But this will cost you more .

Just follow the images below :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]